# OOP Nomenclature: what's the name for the full type name in Curiously Recurring Template Pattern?

Tags: java, c++, oop

Curiously Recurring Template Pattern is Jim Coplien's name for a generic base class whose actual generic argument is a derived class:

```
class Base<T> { ... }
class Derived: public Base<Derived> { ... }
```

Or in Java, for example, Comparable and Enums:

```
class Foo implements Comparable<Foo> { ... }
//or
enum Bar { ... } //  which is actually Bar extends Enum<Bar>
```

Now, the type names of these classes are, in order, `Derived`, `Foo`, and `Bar`.

But what do we call the things that also specify the derivation, that is,  'Derived is-a Base<Derived>', 'Foo implements Comparable<Foo>', 'Bar extends Enum<Bar>'. This isn't the *type name*, it's something more.

But what's the *word* for that typename-plus-derivation-name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is F-bounded polymorphism. The F-bound is the constraint:

```
interface I<A extends I<A>>
//            ^----------^
```

and it appears in subtypes as

```
class C extends I<C>
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java, it's given in the [language spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.4):

> Given a (possibly generic) class declaration `C<F1,...,Fn>` `(n ≥ 0, C ≠ Object)`, the **direct superclass** of the class type `C<F1,...,Fn>` is the type given in the extends clause of the declaration of `C` if an extends clause is present, or `Object` otherwise.

and

> Given a (possibly generic) class declaration `C<F1,...,Fn>` `(n ≥ 0, C ≠ Object)`, the **direct superinterfaces** of the class type `C<F1,...,Fn>` are the types given in the implements clause of the declaration of `C`, if an implements clause is present.

So, it's just called the direct superclass or direct superinterface. There is no special name for the fact that it is "curiously recurring".